# Проблемы с кодировкой в openserver

Tags: php, utf-8, openserver

Дело в том, что после обновления openserver перестал работать один из сайтов. Выдает следующую ошибку:

> PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Код, в котором ошибка (2 строка):

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=root";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
```

Полагаю, что проблемы с кодировкой, в my.ini выставлено utf-8. Еще заметил, что в phpmyadmin выставлена кодировка utf8mb4, может быть в этом дело?

Comment: Это помогло? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep

Comment: нет, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: А вы как обновляли OpenServer?